# Keeping order on hash map keys during collecting them

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I have the following hash map

```
Map<String,Double> map_1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

with some keys: e.g. ["hello_1", "hello_2", "hello_3"].

Then, I iterate through these keys using stream API and saving new results in map2:

```
 Map<String,Double> map_2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 map_2 = map_1.keySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry, 
                                entry -> {
                                     Double value = map_1.get(entry);
                                     return (value + 5);
                                }));
```

but the new hash map has keys in another order, despite it is defined as LinkedHashMap. I think the problem is during stream + collect steps.

Anyone could suggest me a solution?
Thanks

Comment: There is no sense in initializing `map_2` with a `LinkedHashMap` instance, you are overwriting it with an entirely different object when assigning a new value to the `map_2` variable. By the way, if you want to add `5` to all values of a `Map`, you can simple use `map_1.replaceAll((key,value) -> value+5);` to do it in-place. If you still need a second map, `Map<String,Double> map_2=new LinkedHashMap<>(map_1); map_2.replaceAll((key,value) -> value+5);` can do it.

Comment: map_1.keySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry, 
                                entry -> map_1.get(entry) +5,
                               (e1,e2)-> e1,
                                 LinkedHashMap::new));

Answer (score 0):

The order of the keys actually gets messed up in the collect step in this case.

You need to specify that you want to collect to a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Could you explain what I have to specify?